# fetching express back-end with react return 405 error (from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight etc...)

Tags: reactjs, express, cors, fetch

I have a small express/react app. I'm running server side on port 5000 and client side on port 3000. I have the following component on the front-end:

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://localhost:5000/auth/google',
    {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
          credentials: 'same-origin',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
      })
      .then(res => { 
        if (!res.ok) {
          throw res;
        }
        return res.json()
      }).then(data => {
        this.setState({loading: false, data});
      }).catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
        this.setState({loading: false, error: true});
      });
  }
```

on the back-end I have this:

```
router.get(
    "/auth/google",
    passport.authenticate("google", { scope: ['Profile','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'] })
);

router.get(
    "/auth/google/callback",
    passport.authenticate("google", { failureRedirect: "/error", session: false }),
    function(req, res) {
        var token = req.user.token;
    request('https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts?access_token=' + token,  
function (error, response, body) {
  console.log(JSON.parse(body).items);
res.send(JSON.parse(body).items)
});
    }
);
```

and here are the error I have:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 ()
```

and

```
Access to fetch at 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5000%2Fauth%2Fgoogle%2Fcallback&scope=Profile%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fanalytics.readonly&client_id=blablabla.apps.googleusercontent.com' (redirected from 'http://localhost:5000/auth/google') from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Answer (score 0):

CORS security violation is triggered by your browser which:

- has got React code (presumably script bundles) from one server,
- is seeing attempts by this code to fetch from another server that is not telling the browser to calm down and tolerate this security violation.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405

This means the browser attempted to contact 'another server' prior to fetch and ask if it should tolerate the security violation but 'another server' refused to talk. Technically speaking, the browser has sent HTTP request using HTTP verb `OPTIONS` and the server responded by indicating it doesn't support this verb.

> Access to fetch at 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/

That's the actual CORS violation detected by the browser which effectively refused to execute fetch.

There are lots of recipes how to calm down the browser so that it would tolerate CORS violations. But the best apprroach is to ensure the violations won't happen so that there is no need to relax the security.

The output of a React application build are .html files and script bundles, possibly source maps. Called build artifacts. If you structure your project so that in both development and production the browser gets everything (build artifacts, API responses) from one single source e.g. Express then there will be no room for CORS issues.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail the last part? build artifacts, API responses? I've rebuilt my app which is now in one server...

Comment: The last part says that if the browser has downloaded the React application (e.g. downloaded the files that the react app consists of) from one server and then sends API requests and gets API responses from the same single server, then there is no possibility, no room to get CORS issues.